# duda sobre como evitar ciertos comportamientos del useParams

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-router-dom

Tengo una duda sobre como plantear el siguiente escenario.

List.tsx

```
interface Props {
  statusEvents: (a: string) => void;
}

const List = ({ statusEvents }: Props) => {
  const match = useRouteMatch();

  const handleStatusEvents = (status: string): void => {
    statusEvents(status);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <ListStyled>
        <li>
          <NavLinkStyled
            activeClassName="link"
            to={`${match.path}/pendientes`}
            onClick={() => handleStatusEvents("pendientes")}
          >
            Pendientes
          </NavLinkStyled>
        </li>
        <li>
          <NavLinkStyled
            activeClassName="link"
            to={`${match.path}/activas`}
            onClick={() => handleStatusEvents("activas")}
          >
            Activas
          </NavLinkStyled>
        </li>
        <li>
          <NavLinkStyled
            activeClassName="link"
            to={`${match.path}/resultados`}
            onClick={() => handleStatusEvents("resultados")}
          >
            Resultados
          </NavLinkStyled>
        </li>
      </ListStyled>
    </>
  );
};

export default List;
```

EventPage.tsx

```
const EventPage = () => {
  const [filter, setFilter] = useState<ICard[]>(ListOfEvents);

  const handleChangeStatusEvents = (status: string): void => {
    let results: ICard[];

    switch (status) {
      case "pendientes":
        results = ListOfEvents.filter((event) => event.isActive === false);
        setFilter(results);
        break;
      case "activas":
        results = ListOfEvents.filter((event) => event.isActive === true);
        setFilter(results);
        break;
      case "resultados":
        results = ListOfEvents;
        setFilter(results);
    }
  };

  return (
    <MainLayout>
      <Spacer height="30" />
      <Title text="Eventos" />
      <Spacer height="30" />
      <List statusEvents={handleChangeStatusEvents} />
      {filter ? <ListEvents events={filter} /> : <EmptyEvents />}
    </MainLayout>
  );
};

export default EventPage;
```

Explico: el `List.tsx` es un menú dentro `EventPage.tsx` que lo que hace es al onClick de cada item del `List.tsx` cambia un componente por otro por el state y lo envía por props al `ListEvents.tsx`(que es un componente que tiene un map y muestra un evento). Entonces se visualizan de un array, los filtrados depende de la selección del menú.

`La url son así: http://localhost:3000/events/pendientes, http://localhost:3000/events/activas, http://localhost:3000/events/resultados`

El problema reside en que ahora estoy creando el componente detalle de cada evento y me encuentro que al hacer uso del useParams, tanto el click del evento, como el de los menús, se van a una página nueva.

`ejemplo: http://localhost:3000/events/evento01`

Me gustaría saber como puedo evitar esto, es decir, que el detalle del evento se vaya a una página nueva, pero que el menú, haga el filtro de la misma pagina donde está, ya que al poner el uso de los params, hace que todo vaya a un componente nuevo.

Routes. tsx

```
const Routes = () => {
  return (
    <Router>
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/events/:id">
          <EventDetailPage event={ListOfEvents} />
        </Route>
        <Route path="/login">
          <LoginPage />
        </Route>
        <Route path="/code">
          <CodePage />
        </Route>
        <Route path="/data">
          <DataPage />
        </Route>
        <Route path="/register">
          <RegisterPage />
        </Route>
        <Route path="/events">
          <EventPage />
        </Route>
        <Route path="/profile">
          <ProfilePage />
        </Route>
      </Switch>
    </Router>
  );
};

export default Routes;
```

Muchas gracias! Saludos!

Comment: Creo que no está soportado usar url completas para react-router ya que los Link funcionan basándose en dónde te encuentras. Supongo que lo querrá por motivos de SEO, quizás puedes poner el link con la url completa y en el onClick hacer un prevent.default() y hacerle un push a la url que te interesa. No me parece muy limpio, así que lo dejo en comentario.

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta @ivanph. No tenia en mente nada relacionado con el SEO, simplemente hacer que funcionen las cosas. El menú que haga el filtro en la misma página y el detalle del evento vaya a otra página. Ahora solo obtengo lo que comentado. Todo se va a la página de detalle, porque coincide la ruta... localhost:3000/event/.... probaré el tema del onClick con un prevent.default()... gracias!

Comment: Entonces ha sido confusión mía de lo que buscabas exactamente. Tienes una página que quieres que muestren los productos con un determinado filtro o otro dependiendo de la url con la que se accede, me pierdo un poco con lo que quieres conseguir. ¿Quieres realizar un filtrado que cambie la url pero que no cambie el componente de la página si ya te encuentras en esa página? Si es así con el hook useHistory(), puedes llamar al método replace que cambia la url sin recargar componentes o poniendo replace=true en los links. Si es la misma página no es mejor usar querys(events?st=activa) en la ruta?

Comment: No te preocupes, yo que me he expresado mal :). Ahora el problema reside en los enlaces del `Link.tsx`. Si uso queries en el to="events?filter=pendientes" por ejemplo, la propiedad active del NavLink del react router dom no funciona, siempre aparece activo (y parece ser que no tiene soporte) y si uso el history no tengo la propiedad Active. La verdad es que no se me ocurren muchas más cosas, y estoy buscando mucho. Si se te ocurren algo más, encantado de escucharlas. Mil gracias!